# SHUTDOWN DEFRAG failing on a big (100+ GB) database

Tags: java, h2

Whenever I call `SHUTDOWN DEFRAG` on my database I end up getting an error (`IllegalStateException` I think) that it can't find a specific Chunk!

I have tried multiple times and I always get the same result that a chunk is missing. The database is big (100+ GB). 
I start with my database that I have which is roughly 4GB and then after it grows to 100+ GB in size defraging the database fails. This has happened a couple of times. 
Before I started the program that grew the database I even tried the recover tool and re-created the 4GB database and then ran `SHUTDOWN DEFRAG` on that database and it worked fine - but again after the database grew to 100+ GB in size `SHUTDOWN DEFRAG` stopped working because it can't find a chunk.

Anyone seen anything like this or anyone know what might be wrong?

I am using: `Windows 2012 R2 (64 bit)`, `Java 8 (1.8.0_102-b14)` and `H2 (1.4.191)`

The stack: 
`

```
2016-07-28 10:21:45 database: close
org.h2.message.DbException: IO Exception: "Closing" [90028-191]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.close(MVTableEngine.java:396)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.closeOpenFilesAndUnlock(Database.java:1386)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.close(Database.java:1286)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.removeSession(Database.java:1170)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.close(Session.java:815)
    at org.h2.command.dml.TransactionCommand.update(TransactionCommand.java:111)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:98)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:258)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:201)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: IO Exception: "Closing" [90028-191]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Chunk 66 not found [1.4.191/6]
    at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:773)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.getChunk(MVStore.java:934)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.readPageChunkReferences(MVStore.java:1368)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.collectReferencedChunks(MVStore.java:1322)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.collectReferencedChunks(MVStore.java:1327)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.collectReferencedChunks(MVStore.java:1327)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.collectReferencedChunks(MVStore.java:1307)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.freeUnusedChunks(MVStore.java:1266)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.storeNowTry(MVStore.java:1054)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.storeNow(MVStore.java:1046)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.commitAndSave(MVStore.java:1035)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.beforeWrite(MVStore.java:2205)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.beforeWrite(MVMap.java:1046)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.copy(MVMap.java:1231)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.copy(MVMap.java:1248)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.copy(MVMap.java:1248)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.copy(MVMap.java:1248)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.copy(MVMap.java:1248)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.copyFrom(MVMap.java:1218)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStoreTool.compact(MVStoreTool.java:517)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStoreTool.compact(MVStoreTool.java:482)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStoreTool.compact(MVStoreTool.java:428)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.close(MVTableEngine.java:385)
    ... 10 more
```

`

Comment: Sounds like the database files are corrupt.  Can you read all existing entries in the database?  Anyway, I would suggest migrating the database content to a new database file and using that instead.

Comment: Yes, I would try to export the data using `script to ...`. If that fails, I suggest to use the `Recover` tool. If that fails, send an email to the H2 Google Group.

Comment: I ran the `Recover` tool on the 4 GB database before I started using it. So it should have been fine before I started using it. 
And I ran my program that grows the 4 GB database a couple of times and each time I get the same error - but sometimes a different chunk number. So I am not sure if this is a regular corrupt database. 
Running the recover tool on a 100 GB database is a bit too much - I don't even have nearly enough disk space for that. I don't mind starting from scratch again with the 4GB database but I don't want a corrupt database when it gets to 100 GB again.